# Possible to configure (Squid) proxy so a browser can bypass a VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, openvpn, squid

I want to do the following (if it's possible):

Have 1 browser (say Firefox) as normal - all traffic uses my VPN.
Have another browser (say Chrome) where all traffic bypasses the VPN.

I have already setup a PC with a VPN using OpenVPN and I understand how to add static routes so that access to specific IP addresses will bypass the VPN.

I thought what I want to do may be possible by setting up a (Squid) proxy server which routes all traffic outside of the VPN, and then configure the Chrome browser to use that proxy server. Unless there is a better/easier way?

But I do not know how to accomplish this and configure Squid/routes despite doing a lot of reading and experimenting (I am not a network expert), nor have I been able to find any resource to tell me how (or if it's possible).

Any help or links to information appreciated.

Comment: I thought you could enable split tunneling with Openvpn??? is that not the effect you are looking for?

Comment: Where do you want to run your Squid proxy ? If you want to run it on some other PC (server), you need a host route from your browser and you don't need a separate namespace. If you want to run quid on the same machine as the browsers, you don't need a Squid proxy and should follow Anonymous's answer.

Comment: @Juergen at the moment I am just trying to get something running on a single PC (which is sort-of my server). Although if I get something working, in future I would like to get it working on another PC which I could either setup the same as the first or route through the server, depending on the final solution.

Comment: @WU-TANG although I understand the basic concept of split tunnelling, I don't know if that could help me or how to set it up, hence my original question. I am just using the NordVPN service, so if it's possible to use split tunnelling to achieve what I want to do I would like to hear more.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/271915/961781 might help

Comment: I think your conversation with @ofirule gave me a little more clarity. I believe the split tunneling would have been pretty close to his answer... and since I see now that it is not "your" vpn, I don't know if there is a way for you to configure it if it isn't already an option(ie. like with cisco anyconnect clients, there is a checkbox for split tunneling... and then the default routing for the machine doesn't change, the site's network I am connecting to just gets added as a route and i get a second IP added to my box... vice my one NIC just getting the new IP and the def route changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the ideas and comments so far. I have not (yet) got `firejail` to work with the VPN active (@Anonymous suggestion). But I followed up on the suggestion linked by @ofirule specifically [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1048913) to use control groups.

That answer has a link to a complete shell script to do everything automatically but I wanted to do things manually at least to start with so I could follow along and make sure I knew exactly what I was changing. So, following the Manual HowTo there I will post below exactly what I did for anyone else.

Note that my network interface is named **enp0s31f6** and my gateway IP is **192.168.0.1** I think those are the only two specific things that may need changing for others following this:

```
# Install required tools
sudo apt-get install cgroup-lite cgroup-tools

sudo su

# Define a control group named novpn with a classid of 11:11
cd /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls
mkdir novpn
cd novpn
echo 0x00110011 > net_cls.classid

# Add mark 11 on packets of classid 0x00110011
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -j MARK --set-mark 11

# Force the packets to exit through my interface (enp0s31f6) with NAT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE

# Define a new "novpn" routing table
echo 11 novpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# Packets with mark 11 will use novpn
ip rule add fwmark 11 table novpn

# Add a route for default gateway for novpn
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table novpn

# Unset reverse path filtering for all interfaces
# My PREVIOUS VALUES: lo was 0, others (all, default, enp0s31f6) were 2 in case I need to revert back.
for i in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter; do echo 0 > $i; done

exit

# Create control group    
sudo cgcreate -t $USER:$USER -a $USER:$USER -g net_cls:novpn

# Run app on specific novpn interface (close all browser windows first)
killall firefox
cgexec -g net_cls:novpn firefox
```

I don't (yet) fully understand all the above but it works! :-) Running firefox via the `cgexec` command I can check my IP in firefox with the VPN active and can see it reports my actual public IP not the VPN IP. I also proved this method works by running a radio streaming service which was having issues working with the VPN - it now works absolutely fine bypassing the VPN.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best would be to change nothing to your current setup but to take advantage of **Linux namespaces** instead. You can use tools like nsjail or Firejail for convenience.

The idea would be to set up a dedicated namespace for that other browser that should bypass the VPN, with its own routing rules. That's all you need, change the routing rules so that it uses your regular Ethernet interface rather than the tun interface created by OpenVPN.

The other benefit is **isolation** of your applications. By limiting their scope and the resources they are able to see, you effectively isolate them from each other.

Using Firejail here is how I would do it roughly - I encourage you to read the doc to fine-tune the configuration to the desired result. Firejail comes with ready to use profiles for common applications so it can immediately start sandboxing your browsers and other applications.

There is a also GUI configuration tool (firetools) but my suggestion would be to try Firejail with just one application instead of reconfiguring your whole environment.

Here is a PoC using **Python** (assuming you have the **netifaces** package installed).

```
firejail --net=enp4s0 --noprofile python3

>>> import netifaces
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo', 'eth0-11182']
```

As you can see, Python sees only one interface (in addition to the loopback interface). eth0-11182 is of course a virtual interface that exists only within the current namespace.

Suggested reading: [Firefox Sandboxing Guide](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/firefox-guide/)

Comment: I have been giving this a go today. Without the VPN active it all works o.k. e.g. using a `--net=` to specify my networking interface. However if I try it with the VPN active I get no access to remote networks. For example, if I firejail `bash` rather than `firefox` I can ping my local network addresses, but `ping 1.1.1.1` results in `Network is unreachable`. With VPN inactive firejail bash `route` shows 2 entries: `default/192.168.0.1 (my router)` and `192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0`. With the VPN active I only get the last `192.168.0.0` route. Any idea why it's not working with the VPN?

Comment: You need to setup a route in the namespace as Anonymous wrote ("with its own routing rules"). But this is not sufficient, you also need to setup a DNS server: Compare `/etc/resolv.conf` with and without VPN outside the namespace..

Comment: @Juergen I am not sure what you mean by "setup  a route in the namespace". resolv.conf is always just `nameserver 127.0.0.1` with/without VPN and inside/outside firejail. At this stage I am just trying to ping an internet IP address (1.1.1.1) so DNS should not be an issue at this stage. All I am doing is running a test specifying my network interface not the `tun0` interface as suggested by @Anonymous above: `firejail --net=enp0s31f6 --ip=192.168.0.9 --noprofile bash` Like I said this works without VPN but not with the VPN active but I don't know what else I should be doing.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, too, because I don't know the `firejail` program recommended here. Following the idea of this answer, you may want to try `firejail route add default gw <gateway>` where gateway is your router, thus bypassing the VPN in the namespace. (Outside the namespace where VPN is active, you should see a host route of the VPN server to your router that is used by the VPN software to communicate outside.) If this is not possible, seems you need to read the docs linked above if you want to follow the approach outlined in this answer. And DNS will come later ...

Comment: What does your routing table look like when you run bash under Firejail ? Eg: `route -n` and `ip link`

Comment: @Anonymous - with VPN inactive firejail bash route -n shows 2 entries: 0.0.0.0/192.168.0.1 (which is my router IP) and 192.168.0.0/0.0.0.0 With the VPN active I only get the last 192.168.0.0//0.0.0.0 entry. The results for `ip link` seem to be the same either way, it lists `1: lo` and the firejail created interface as something like `2: eth0-1938287` with all the details looking the same between VPN active/inactive. So I guess the issue/question is why is firejail replicating the default interface route when VPN is inactive but not when the VPN is active?

Comment: I can't test right now but I think the key would be to create a virtual interface (bridge). See this: [Firejail Usage](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/basic-usage/) - check the section that mentions brctl. Might require a few firewall rules too.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `squid`, but to my understanding it's just a regular proxy, so by installing it on your computer, it still follows your OS routing rules.

I would try the following setup:

1. Configure OpenVPN to **not** change your default gateway
2. Install squid or some other proxy service on the same machine running your OpenVPN server

After having this setup configured, your browsers would not use the VPN by default, and you can configure one of them to go via the proxy server using the server's OpenVPN subnet address.

**Note1:** You have to use the proxy via the OpenVPN subnet address and not its public IP.

**Note2:** Do not allow traffic to the proxy server port from outside of the OpenVPN subnet, can be achieved using iptables, or by not opening the port using your cloud provider rules

### UPDATE:

When using an external VPN service (e.g: nordVPN) you don't have access to the machine running the OpenVPN server and that makes the above solution invalid, since you can't install anything on the machine running the OpenVPN server.

It's possible to install the proxy service in another device in your local subnet, and some router (e.g: [mikrotik](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Proxy)) provide this feature. But that will make the solution to work only on a specific location with this setup.

Comment: I am not sure I exactly follow, I am just using NordVPN service so the gateway is just a NordVPN server/port. I am not running my own VPN, it's just configured via Ubuntu Network Settings.

Comment: So NordVPN is your VPN server, which means that you don't have access to the machine running the OpenVPN server, and can't install anything there. This solution won't work in that case. I will post an update for your case, but I think that @Anonymous solution with some updates is a better fit